# Spread/rest operator includes properties from target type that are not on on destination type

Tags: typescript, operators

I've noticed that when spreading properties from `A` into `B`, where `A` extends `B`, all of the properties from `A` are included even though they do not exist on `B`.

For example:

```
interface B {
  name: string;
}

interface A extends B {
  age: number;
}

const fullThing: A = { age: 21, name: 'Bob' };

const thing: B = { ...fullThing };

console.log(thing);
```

Output:

```json
{
  "age": 21,
  "name": "Bob"
}
```

Is there any way to work around this, so as `B` only gets the properties from `A` which actually exist on B? In my case, the desired output would be:

```json
{
  "name": "Bob"
}
```

Comment: TypeScript types are [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) and do not exist at runtime.  If you want to omit properties you'll need to do it explicitly in some way, like [possibly this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wQq5Yw).  See the linked questions/answers for more information